# How to subset a data frame with R pipeline

Tags: r, tidyverse, pipeline

I am trying to subset/filter a data frame according to the corresponding column elements from another data frame.
Here is what I used to do this

```
df <- df1[df1$col1 %in% df2$col2,]
```

And then I am going to set the column as row names

```
df <- df %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames('col1')
```

However I have no idea how to combine these two codes into one using `%>%`

Comment: Use filter for first operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 %>% filter(col1 %in% df2$col2) %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames('col1')
```